# Get id and update database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to be able to update my database with an input field based on each record available.

I have this code which will update the record but obviously I have to change the id for it to work with each record.

```
Vaccines::where('id', 2)->update($request->all());
```

How can I get the id for each record and update each one based on the id?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
Vaccines::all()->each->update($request->all());
```

You don't need the records ID in this case. Eloquent will fetch all records for your model and return a collection.

Edit:

You would need to post each model attribute as an array. Index by the models primary key and assign the respective value.

```
 // using a list of User records as an example
 <form>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
      <input name="first_name[{{ $user->id }}]" value="{{ $user->first_name }}" />
      <input name="last_name[{{ $user->id }}]" value="{{ $user->last_name }}" />
     @endforeach
 </form>

 // submit the form...


 // in your `update` controller method
 foreach(request()->input('first_name') as $id => $value) {
     if ($user = User::find($id)) {
         $user->update(['first_name' => $value]);
     } else {
         logger(sprintf('Unable to find model id %d.', $id));
     }
 }
```

That give you a idea on how to handle it?

Comment: Sorry I guess wasn't clear enough, I want to be able to update all records seperately not all at once.

Comment: I've updated my answer but I'm not sure if it's what you had in mind.

Comment: That seems to do the same thing as before(update all records instead of just one). Basically i want each record to be editable and re-submitted through a form updating the database for only that record.

Comment: So like a table with 1 row for each record where you can edit the rows independently and then bulk update all the records with their respective changes?

Comment: Essentially yes that is what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Ok check my answer now, hopefully that gets you what you need.

Comment: Really close, I had it working before but i'm getting the following now(no idea why it stopped working): Call to a member function update() on null – with this `code  foreach(request()->input('stock') as $id => $vaccines) {
         Vaccines::find($id)->update(['stock' => $vaccines]);
      }`

Comment: Updated my answer with a safety check and a logging statement to determine which id is failing.

Comment: No errors the page refreshes but nothing updates this is my form `code
    <form class="vaccine-add-form" name="vaccine-add-form" method="POST">
      <?PHP echo csrf_field() ?>
      <select name="vaccine_name[{{ $vaccines->vaccine_name }}]" value="{{ $vaccines->vaccine_name }}">
        <option value="HEP A">HEP A</option>
        <option value="HEP B">HEP B</option>
        <option value="HEP C">HEP C</option>
      </select>
      <input name="stock[{{ $vaccines->stock }}]" value="{{ $vaccines->stock }}" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Records">
 </form> `

Comment: When trying to add a new record with my other form i get this Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `code    foreach(request()->input('stock') as $id => $vaccines) {
      if($vaccines = Vaccines::find($id)) {
        $vaccines->update(['stock' => $vaccines]);
      } else {
        logger(sprintf('Unable to find id %d.', $id));
      }
 
      }
  `

Comment: Got this error Method App\Vaccines::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\JsonEncodingException: Error encoding model [App\Vaccines] with ID [111] to JSON: Recursion detected

Comment: Updating has started to work again, I am so confused. What caused me to have the errors with  a call to a member function update() on null started when I deleted record with id 111, then creating a new record with that id made it start to come back and changing to this `code   foreach(request()->input('stock') as $id => $vaccines) {
         Vaccines::find($id)->update(['stock' => $vaccines]);
      }` made it work mostly